# Keithley2400_IV Sweep_VIA RS232 - I'd like to increase the size of ':FETCh?'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, serial-port, fetch, pyvisa

I'm Kwon, an engineering student. I'm currently producing IV Sweep from keithley2400 products and from Python through rs232.
While looking at the manual, I was trying to compensate for various errors and hit a dead end. I'm going to draw a graph with matplotlib, but the number of xvalues and yvalues is not correct.
After several attempts, I found that 'yvalues' were fixed to a size of 5.
(The graph came out well when each size was adjusted to 5.)
The contents of the manual are as follows.

```
"You can specify from one to all five elements."
```

Please help me to increase the size of ':FETCh?' from 5 so that I can draw a graph that connects the steps I put in. Thank you for reading the long question.

```
    import sys
    startv = sys.argv[1]
    stopv = sys.argv[2]
    stepv = sys.argv[3]
    filename = sys.argv[4]
    startvprime = float(startv)
    stopvprime = float(stopv)
    stepvprime = float(stepv)
    steps = (stopvprime - startvprime) / stepvprime + 1

    # Import PyVisa and choose RS-232 as Drain-Source
    import pyvisa, time
    import serial
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    rm.list_resources()
    with rm. open_resource('COM3') as Keithley:
        Keithley.port = 'COM3'
        Keithley.baudrate = 9600
        Keithley.timeout = 25000


    Keithley.open()
    Keithley.read_termination = '\r'
    Keithley.write_termination = '\r'
    Keithley.write("*RST")
    Keithley.write("*IDN?")


    Keithley.write(":SENS:FUNC:CONC OFF")                  
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:FUNC VOLT")                      
    Keithley.write(":SENS:FUNC 'CURR:DC' ")                 


    Keithley.write(":SOUR:VOLT:START ", startv)
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:VOLT:STOP ", stopv)               
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:VOLT:STEP ", stepv)              
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:SWE:RANG AUTO")                   


    Keithley.write(":SENS:CURR:PROT 0.1")                     
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:SWE:SPAC LIN")                    
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:SWE:POIN", str(int(steps)))      
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:SWE:DIR UP")
    Keithley.write(":TRIG:COUN", str(int(steps)))
    Keithley.write(":FORM:ELEM CURR")


    Keithley.write(":SOUR:VOLT:MODE SWE")                   
    Keithley.write(":OUTP ON")                             


    import numpy as np
    result = Keithley.query(":READ?")                       
    yvalues = Keithley.query_ascii_values(":FETCh?")
    Keithley.write(":OUTP OFF")
    Keithley.write(":SOUR:VOLT 0")


    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
    from scipy import stats
    xvalues = np.arange(startvprime, stopvprime+1, stepvprime)  
    plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
    plt.xlabel(' Drain-Source Voltage (V)')
    plt.ylabel(' Drain-Source Current (mA)')
    plt.title('IV Curve')
    plt.show()
    np.savetxt(filename, (xvalues,yvalues))
```

Answer (score 0):

error ex) python name.py -10 10 1 savename
=> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (21,) and (5,)

Answer (score 0):

What is yvalues in your code? I think yvalues's type is string because of pyvisa's query_ascii_values.

```
yvalues = [float(i) for i in Keithley.query_ascii_values(":FETCh?")]
```

Also, check 'steps' value.